# Circle with straight lines

Tags: modeling, objects

I'm attempting to make a circle with straight lines (in the picture) - I need it to remain whole.

Any advice on how to go about this? The bisector tool kept saying 'error: selected edges/faces required', but I've seen people cutting it by simply dragging across before?

[image]

Comment: Do you just want to extract that set of edges from a sphere, as shown?

Answer (score 1):

You could try a UV Sphere with a *Cast* modifier set to *Cuboid*.

[image]

Moving the *Subdivision Surface* modifier before or after *Cast* will give different results, and the *Factor* affects how concave/convex the resulting mesh will be.